# Naming the Drop down menu - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a custom map of Somalia. I have posted the code in this fiddler here

http://jsfiddle.net/nr7dU/

I 'm trying to get the dropdown menu in the right hand corner (the title displaying is blank) to display the title custom. I believe the troublesome code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name:"Custom"}); 
var myOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.0442, 45.7194),
mapTypeControl: true,
streetViewControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `mapTypeIds`-options-option of `mapTypeControlOptions`:

```
mapTypeIds:
 ['map_style',google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MTbv7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MTbv7/)